# How can I see if a customer has another specific subscription starting after an earlier one by looking at the stop and start date?

Tags: r, loops, date, for-loop

The dataframe that I am working with contains entries of subscriptions with a start and stop date of the subscription. A user can have multiple rows since he/she can have or had multiple subscriptions. I would like to know if a certain subscription is followed up by another subscription.

I have considered using a for loop since the amount of observations is not particularly high (approx. 2000). However, my knowledge on this subject is not particularly high so I couldn't manage to create one. Each user has its own ID code. There are different types of subscriptions possible. I have created a dummy variable for the specific subscription of which I want to check if it is followed up on.

An example of what the data looks like:

```
id startdate stopdate subscriptiontype
1   2013-05-01  2013-06-01  1
2   2010-05-02  2012-05-02  3
2   2013-05-02  2013-06-02  1
2   2013-07-23  2013-12-23  2
4   2008-05-02  2011-05-02  3
4   2013-05-04  2013-06-04  1
```

I would like to see for each 'id' if there is another subscription with a starting date after the stopdate of subscription type 1. Would this be possible? Thank you for reading!

**DATA**

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4), startdate = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("2008-05-02", "2010-05-02", "2013-05-01", 
"2013-05-02", "2013-05-04", "2013-07-23"), class = "factor"), 
    stopdate = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("2011-05-02", 
    "2012-05-02", "2013-06-01", "2013-06-02", "2013-06-04", "2013-12-23"
    ), class = "factor"), subscriptiontype = c(1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
    1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: For id 2, we see `2013-07-03` as a starting date. What if we have `2013-07-05`? How would you want to handle it? Are they the same type of information?

Comment: Thank you for the response! In this case I just chose the next day, but further in the future could be a possibility too. The start date and stop date are standard variables indicating the length of the subscription. I just want to know if subscription type 1 is being followed up on. The time frame for a future subscription is not really important in this case.

Comment: To add some context, the subscription type of interest is a trial subscription, and the information that I would like to know is if this trial subscription is being followed up on with a paid subscription to see if the trial subscriptions actually work.

Comment: Given what you said, you want to check if there is more than one row for each `id` in the data. If you have two rows for one ID, that means there is type2 subscription. Would this be the case?

Comment: Not exactly. Older subscriptions are in the dataset as well. An example: User X has had a paid subscription for 2 years up until 2012, a few months later user X has had a trial subscription for a month, after the trial user X has signed up for a paid subscription. This would mean that there are three rows present. The only points of interest are the trial subscription and the following subscription for user X.

Comment: Could you revise your sample data in a way that reflects your data's characteristics? That would help people here to help you.

Comment: I have expanded it a bit, thank you

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. With this updated data, you want to find a row with subscription type 2 which follows subscription type 2. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, a bit more in general. I want to find out if subscription type 1 is followed up by any other kind of subscription (there are a lot in the actual dataset). So for a user who has had subscription type 1, if there is a starting date for any other type of subscription after the stop date of subscription type 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207772/discussion-between-joep-and-jazzurro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your data a little bit more and did the following. For each group, I think you want to check if there is any subscription type follows subscription type 1. First, I converted two columns to class date, just in case. Then, for each `ID`, I ran logical checks. Basically, I am asking "Is the previous value in `subscriptiontype` 1?".

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mutate_at(mydf, vars(contains("date")),
          .funs = list(~ymd(.))) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(check = lag(subscriptiontype) == 1)

     id startdate  stopdate   subscriptiontype check
  <int> <date>     <date>                <int> <lgl>
1     1 2013-05-01 2013-06-01                1 NA   
2     2 2010-05-02 2012-05-02                3 NA   
3     2 2013-05-02 2013-06-02                1 FALSE
4     2 2013-07-23 2013-12-23                2 TRUE 
5     4 2008-05-02 2011-05-02                3 NA   
6     4 2013-05-04 2013-06-04                1 FALSE
7     7 2018-01-01 2018-02-01                3 NA   
8     7 2018-03-01 2018-03-15                1 FALSE
9     7 2018-04-01 2018-05-15                4 TRUE
```

**DATA**

```
mydf <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L), startdate = c("2013-05-01", 
"2010-05-02", "2013-05-02", "2013-07-23", "2008-05-02", "2013-05-04", 
"2018-01-01", "2018-03-01", "2018-04-01"), stopdate = c("2013-06-01", 
"2012-05-02", "2013-06-02", "2013-12-23", "2011-05-02", "2013-06-04", 
"2018-02-01", "2018-03-15", "2018-05-15"), subscriptiontype = c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))

  id  startdate   stopdate subscriptiontype
1  1 2013-05-01 2013-06-01                1
2  2 2010-05-02 2012-05-02                3
3  2 2013-05-02 2013-06-02                1
4  2 2013-07-23 2013-12-23                2
5  4 2008-05-02 2011-05-02                3
6  4 2013-05-04 2013-06-04                1
7  7 2018-01-01 2018-02-01                3
8  7 2018-03-01 2018-03-15                1
9  7 2018-04-01 2018-05-15                4
```

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed what I mean. However, would it be possible to do this check only for individual users based on their id? In this instance, it classifies the previous one as TRUE between users 7 and 4 as well since user 4's last subscription was of type 1.

Comment: @Joep `group_by()` defines groups; each individual is separated in data manipulation. Hence, the first row for id 7 is NA although the last row for id 4 contains 1. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I was looking at my own results. Strangely enough it gives a TRUE value when I run the exact code that you provided, not NA like in your provided example, which is indeed what I am aiming for. Only the first value returns NA, the second row also comes back as TRUE

Comment: @Joep I do not have your real data. So you gotta work on the rest of the data manipulation unless you can provide sample data that reflects what you said.

Comment: No, I mean your provided example. If I copy your exact dput and command, I get different output than you.

Answer (score 1):

You can self-join the table. You first filter the users based on whether they have subscription type "1", then join for any other subscription type. You then check whether a user has another subscription (2,3,4) which starts after the first ends. Finally, you can collapse by user using "summarise" to see whether our conditions are true.

```
    library(dplyr)

    mydf%>%
    filter(subscriptiontype==1)%>%
    full_join(mydf[mydf$subscriptiontype!=1,], by="id", suffix=c(".Type1",".OtherType"))%>%
    mutate(check=as.Date(startdate.OtherType)>=as.Date(stopdate.Type1))%>%
    group_by(id)%>%
    summarise(any(check, na.rm = TRUE))

    id `any(check, na.rm = TRUE)`
    <dbl> <lgl>                     
    1     FALSE                     
    2     TRUE                      
    4     FALSE
```